# Autocomplete from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get autocomplete to work on a second column

I have code that works to autocomplete from a source sheet column A into another sheet column C , I need this to be replicated to autocomplete a second column from a second column in the same source sheet, from column B to column D.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     'Sub "autocompletes" data entered into column C using a source table on a different worksheet. If more than one match is
     '    found, the user is allowed to continue entering characters until a unique match is found. If no matches are found, the
     '    data is accepted as entered. ALT + Enter, Enter to force the macro to accept data as entered. The sub is triggered by
     '    the Enter key.
    Dim cel As Range, match1 As Range, match2 As Range, rg As Range, targ As Range

     '***Please adjust the next two statements before using this code!***
    Set targ = Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) 'Watch the cells in column C
    Set rg = Worksheets("Client list").Range("A:A") 'Use named range AutoCompleteText for "autocomplete" info

    If targ Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo errhandler 'If code encounters an error, turn events back on

    For Each cel In targ
        If Not IsError(cel) Then
            If cel <> "" And Right(cel, 1) <> Chr(10) Then
                Set match1 = Nothing
                Set match1 = rg.Find(cel & "*", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) 'Match is case insensitive
                If Not match1 Is Nothing Then
                    Set match2 = rg.FindNext(after:=match1)
                    If match2.Address = match1.Address Then 'Code is fooled by identical strings in two cells
                        cel = match1 'Only one match found. Use it to "autocomplete" the cell
                    Else 'More than one match found. User must enter more data. Return to "Edit" mode
                        cel.Activate
                        Application.SendKeys ("{F2}") 'Begin editing after last character entered
                    End If
                Else 'No matches found. Do not change entered text
                End If
            Else 'Strip the line feed from the end of the text string
                If cel <> "" And Right(cel, 1) = Chr(10) Then cel = Left(cel, Len(cel) - 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next cel


errhandler:     Application.EnableEvents = True

    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds great! What's the question? Are you getting any specific error? Where? Note that Stack Overflow is for getting answers to specific questions, not for general troubleshooting and help implementing features.

Comment: Wouldnt you just want to set a new `targ` and `rg` based on the new criteria and then run a loop through those as you did with the original code?

Comment: Not getting an error it works fine but I have not been able to get it to autocomplete on a second column  I actually have multiple tabs that contain data that my user copies and pastes manually to the load sheet, autocomplete from the other tabs data would be an incredible time saver

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be an easier or faster way to proceed but with your current code you can go this way:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cel As Range, match1 As Range, match2 As Range, rg As Range, targ As Range


For i = 1 to 2

If i = 1 then
    Set targ = Intersect(Target, Range("C:C"))
    Set rg = Worksheets("Client list").Range("A:A")
Elseif i = 2 then
   Set targ = Intersect(Target,Range(“D:D”))
   Set rg = Worksheets(“Client list”).Range(“B:B”)
End If

    If targ Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo errhandler 'If code encounters an error, turn events back on

    For Each cel In targ
        If Not IsError(cel) Then
            If cel <> "" And Right(cel, 1) <> Chr(10) Then
                Set match1 = Nothing
                Set match1 = rg.Find(cel & "*", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) 'Match is case insensitive
                If Not match1 Is Nothing Then
                    Set match2 = rg.FindNext(after:=match1)
                    If match2.Address = match1.Address Then 'Code is fooled by identical strings in two cells
                        cel = match1 'Only one match found. Use it to "autocomplete" the cell
                    Else 'More than one match found. User must enter more data. Return to "Edit" mode
                        cel.Activate
                        Application.SendKeys ("{F2}") 'Begin editing after last character entered
                    End If
                Else 'No matches found. Do not change entered text
                End If
            Else 'Strip the line feed from the end of the text string
                If cel <> "" And Right(cel, 1) = Chr(10) Then cel = Left(cel, Len(cel) - 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next cel

  Next  
errhandler:     Application.EnableEvents = True

    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a syntax error on the else if, it needs straight quotes but anyhow, the solution does not work for column C anymore, I would love to be able to get it done faster and easier but I'm a newbie with VBA.